# How to display a hidden element when the page is opened?

Tags: html, css, hidden

I have a series of `div` elements which I can move around, with only one section visible at a time. This is a simplified example, and that part of it is fine.

My problem is that without a starting link, the main menu is hidden when the page is opened. I don't want that opening link.

What can I do instead of the first link, so that main menu is immediately visible?

```css
.hid {
  display: none;
}

.hid:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href='#main'>Start</a>

<div class='hid' id='main'>
  <h3>This is main menu</h3>
  <p><a href='#menuA'>Goto menu A</a>
    <p><a href='#menuB'>Goto menu B</a>
</div>

<div class='hid' id='menuA'>
  <h3>This is menu A</h3>
  <p><a href='#main'>Goto main menu</a>
    <p><a href='#menuB'>Goto menu B</a>
</div>

<div class='hid' id='menuB'>
  <h3>This is menu B</h3>
  <p><a href='#main'>Goto main menu</a>
    <p><a href='#menuA'>Goto menu A</a>
</div>
```

I want to use only CSS.

Comment: You're already using `:target`. Just add for other targets, to hide the main menu?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman there is no target when the file is opened. On some systems I can open the page with say `mypage.html#main` but others don't recognise that as a valid html file. I have also experimented with `:not(:target)` but to no avail.

Comment: Ahhh, I was about to say `:not(:target)`

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman to hide the main menu? The problem is that the main menu *is* hidden. It seems to be a Catch-22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the main menu the last one. use `display:block` on it then hide it again when one of the other is targeted

```css
.hid {
  display: none;
}

.hid:target,
#main {
  display: block;
}

.hid:target ~ #main {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class='hid' id='menuA'>
  <h3>This is menu A</h3>
  <p><a href='#main'>Goto main menu</a>
    <p><a href='#menuB'>Goto menu B</a>
</div>

<div class='hid' id='menuB'>
  <h3>This is menu B</h3>
  <p><a href='#main'>Goto main menu</a>
    <p><a href='#menuA'>Goto menu A</a>
</div>

<div class='hid' id='main'>
  <h3>This is main menu</h3>
  <p><a href='#menuA'>Goto menu A</a>
    <p><a href='#menuB'>Goto menu B</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that certainly does the goods in the snippet example. I'll examine it in detail a bit later and see if I can make it work in the real code which also has alternative layouts for portrait / landscape and height constraints.